# C# .net Get FullName from Process ID

Tags: c#

how to get FullName(path) from Process ID

For example if int id = 234

how to find the location of id;

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(lvprocesslist.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text); 
string s = Process.GetProcessById(Id).MainModule.FileName; 
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(s));
```

its not working under a windows PID, (notepad with 3704) not working

thankyou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
string s = Process.GetProcessById(2028).MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: You need to replace 2028 with your *Id*

Answer (score 5):

Try `Process.GerProcessById(234).MainModule.FileName`